# Are PCIe v2 RAID controllers backward compatible with PCIe V1?

Tags: raid, sas, lsi, pci-express

I am looking to add a PCIe V.2 RAID controller (LSI SAS 9280-4i4e) to an older Intel server (SR2500) which has PCIe V.1 slots.

Does anyone have any experience with using RAID controllers designed for PCIe V.2 in a PCIe V.1 server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://www.pcisig.com/news_room/faqs/pcie2.0_faq/) on pcisig.com the answer to Question 5 states that PCIe 2.0 cards must be backwardly compatible with PCIe 1.0 and 1.1.  I haven't done this with PCIe cards yet, but the various flavours of 64 bit PCI (66, 100, 133) certainly demonstrated backwards compatibility in my previous experience.  I'm typing this on a machine that has a PCIX-133 ASR-2200s card in a PCIX-100 slot.

If the FAQ is to be believed, in order to be compliant with the PCIe 2.0 standard a card ***must*** be backward compatible.  I would be surprised to find your RAID controller doesn't work, especially on something with a mainstream motherboard chipset.

Comment: I agree, this should just work.

Comment: Thanks guys - I have decided to go ahead with it - i will update with how it goes...

Comment: I ended up with a slightly different version due to availability but it all worked fine and is quick enough for my application - here is the configuration:

LSI SAS 9280-8e
LSI JBOD 630J w/12 X Seagate ST3146356SS

RAID 10 Performance Stats (using SQLIO):

64K Random Write: 1421.63 MBs/sec
64K Random Read: 1118.69 MBs/sec
64K Sequential Write: 1418.04 MBs/sec
64K Sequential Read: 1210.45 MBs/sec

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Sounds like a result then.  Good outcome.